# Is there any synchronized software update mechanism in Bitcoin-Blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, bitcoin-core-development, wallet-development

My question is regarding the update of Bitcoin software. Is there any mechanism for a synchronized software update in the Bitcoin network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the specific software project Bitcoin Core, there is not, and this is very intentional. Core's developers (disclaimer: that includes myself) shouldn't have the power to force new  software onto the network.

Comment: Then how does a change in consensus rules or any of the software module is updated on all the Bitcoin nodes?

Comment: There isn't. People must choose to run new software of they want new rules.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Bitcoin is a *protocol*, and there are many different implementations of the protocol developed by many different people and groups. It would not make sense to distribute "new software" to all the different implementations.